# Prove that if all the $78$ vertices of a graph have at least degree $5$, then the graph must have a cycle 6.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a $78$ member company everyone knows at least $5$ others. We sit them around 6-person tables. Prove that in every case there is a seating when at least at one table everybody knows his neighbors.

I think it's a proof by contradiction. Assume that the graph where the vertices are the people and the edges are the relation has no $6$ long cycle. How does it limit the sum of the degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's false.

First, make 15 5-cliques, to cover 75 people. 
Divide these into 3 sets of 5 cliques, and add one person to each.
The extra person knows 1 person in each clique.

These 3 disconnected graphs have no 6-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The counterexample seems to be incorrect. Those in the 5-cliques not being connected to any of the 3 extra persons have only 4 acquaintances.